# Is there a 'execution date' or run date parameter in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, date, pyspark, spark-streaming, azure-databricks

I want to run a script for historical data (2022 data_ that is stored in the azure data lake gen 2 in date directory format yyyy/mm/dd)

Steps:1

1. for each date in 2022 i want to pull in data for the last 10/ or so number of days
2. perform some calculations on it i.e. calculate the rate based on last 10 days
3. write this dataframe to data lake again in a separate folder such as changed/yyyy/mm/dd

Is there an existing execution date parameter in pyspark?

currently for (present) time e.g. todays date 27/02/2023 I will pull in data from the last 10 days (dates 27th Feb - 17th feb), calculate the rate and then send to folder 2023/02/27. I do this by setting two variables start*Date and end*Date , using the datetime,now() function as the start date and end_date as timedelta(10) . I need to be able to do thsis whole process  for historical data .

Comment: What do you mean by an execution date parameter?

Comment: e.g. the date the cell/script is executed. so if i set the execution date as 01/01/2023 then the .datetimenow() would return 01/01/2023

Comment: Still unclear. It seems like you are able to achieve what you want. Could you please elaborate on what exactly (with examples if possible) you are looking for? (add info to the question, instead of commenting)

Comment: So you want the variable value to be the time when the script is executed? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code as template to achieve the requirement.

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
import pandas as pd

last = datetime.strptime('2023-03-01', '%Y-%m-%d')        #the final day until which you want to read data
first = datetime.strptime('2023-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')     #the day from which you want to start reading data from
current_date = last
while (current_date >= first):   #performing operations for each day (using 10 previoud days from current date) until first day i.e., 2023-01-01
    end_date = current_date- timedelta(days=10)    #to read files between these 10 days
    file_paths = [f"/mnt/container/{single_date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')}/*.parquet" for single_date in pd.date_range(end_date, current_date, freq='D')]

    print(file_paths)
    #read files here
    #perform operations here
    
    current_date = current_date - timedelta(1)
```

[image]

- The `current_date` would be the day folder to which you will be writing data to after you perform your calculations/operations on dataframe.